# How can I create a guided tour of my page in a Blazor app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I build those tutorial call outs for new features in my Blazor app? I'm not even sure what its called, I keep getting building your first app stuff. smh lol

In other words, when you are new to the app you get these call outs to what's what in your app. smh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [Shepherd](https://shepherdjs.dev) in the past to build an interactive tour in my Blazor app.

My approach is:

1. Decorate the objects that I want to highlight with a custom attribute
2. Define the tour steps in an HTML block somewhere (preferably using razor components to do it the Blazor way)
3. Trigger the tour using an event handler that calls a custom JS function
4. Build the Shepherd tour from the tour steps built in step 2

This allows you to define as many tours as you want in the same page. Building the tour on demand means that you can be sure the HTML has already been rendered by Blazor rather than taking a JS-first approach.

**1. Decorate the tour targets**

Add custom attributes to your existing HTML elements that you wish to highlight as part of a tour.

I have used the attribute `data-tour-step`, but it would make sense to use a suitable namespace.

```html
<div data-tour-step="first-object">
  This is the first object I want to highlight
</div>
<div>
  Some object that I don't want to highlight
</div>
<div data-tour-step="second-object">
  This is the second object I want to highlight
</div>
```

**2. Define the tour steps**

I define my tour steps in razor components, giving a name to the tour (which we will use later), and a series of steps that refer back to the step names we created in step 1. The description will be presented during the tour.

I have used plain text for the purposes of this example, but Shepherd does allow for HTML here (you can work out how to do this from the docs).

```
<TourContainer Name="My-Tour">
  <TourStep Target="first-object">Some tour step description</TourStep>
  <TourStep Target="second-object">Some other tour step description</TourStep>
</TourContainer>
```

TourContainer.razor

```
<div data-tour-name="@Name">
  @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
 
  [Parameter]
  public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

TourStep.razor

```
<div data-tour-step data-target="@Target">
  @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
 
  [Parameter]
  public string? Target { get; set; }
}
```

**3. Trigger the tour**

Use some event handler to call a JS function that we will define in step 4. We only need to pass in the name of the tour - everything else has already been defined.

```
<button @onclick="() => StartTour("My-Tour")">Start the tour!</button>

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
  private async Task StartTour(string name)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("tour.start", name);
  }
}
```

**4. Build and run the Shepherd tour**

Here I add a function to the window object so that it can be called from Blazor.

Given a tour name, we:

1. Create a Shepherd tour instance
2. Find the element with the tour name
3. For each step in the tour container, find the target element and add the step to the Shepherd tour
4. Start the tour

```
(function() {
  window.tour = {
    start: name => {
            // create a Shepherd tour
      const tour = new Shepherd.Tour({
        useModalOverlay: true,
        defaultStepOptions: {
            classes: 'shadow-md bg-purple-dark',
            scrollTo: true
        }
      });
      
      // add the steps from our step container
      const containerEl = document.querySelector(`[data-tour-name="${name}"]`);
      const stepEls = containerEl.querySelectorAll('[data-tour-step]');
      stepEls.forEach(stepEl => {
        const stepName = stepEl.getAttribute('data-target');
        const target = document.querySelector(`[data-tour-step="${stepName}"]`);
      
        // add the step to the Shepherd tour
        tour.addStep({
            // you would need to take a better approach when not just dealing with plain text
            text: stepEl.innerHTML,
            attachTo: {
                element: target,
                on: 'bottom'
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Next',
                    action: tour.next
                }
            ]
        });
      }); 
      
      tour.start();                  
    }
  };
})();
```

Basic example here: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/skrry93w. I am not using razor components here, but the approach is the same in general.

Comment: Tour! Lol, I couldn’t think of any words for my search, smh. Thank you.

Comment: lol. No problem. Btw, I'm not necessarily endorsing Shepherd as the best solution - I just landed on it when I first when searching (about a year ago) and it suited me, so I kept it. There may even be a Blazor-specific library out there.